# Plasmashell High CPU Load Fix - Plasma 5.15 KDE on Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: kde, 19.04, plasma-5

Running `top` shows that plasmashell was just eating CPU. The culprit, it seems, is a long-standing KDE bug that apparently rears its ugly head every now and then.

Temporary fix: run:

```
killall plasmashell; plasmashell &
```

... from a terminal, and it *SHOULD* drop back to normal. The problem, it seems, is with the notification icon(s) in your system tray ... get one, or have one with an animation (weather? Network? New mail?), and you'll get the spike.

Comment: when plasmashell suddenly starts eats up 100% of CPU , first thing we should check, it is if is only with our user, i.e. crate another user and login with the new user and check if plasmashell is fine, if is fine you know that something in you configuration is bad. After you may try many things, start an empty session, clean history of clipboard . Or even move all yours .kde files and add it again piece by piece. The main goal of my answer is that probably something happened to the user configuration that makes plasmashell go crazy and if you try a new user you can check that .

Answer (score 1):

Editing the `/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.notifications/contents/ui/NotificationIcon.qml` file *seems* to do the trick (your mileage may vary). Look for this section:

```
PlasmaComponents.BusyIndicator {
    anchors.fill: parent 

    visible: jobs ? jobs.count > 0 : false
    running: visible
}
```

..and change it to read:

```
 PlasmaComponents.BusyIndicator {
    anchors.fill: parent

    visible: jobs ? jobs.count > 0 : false
    running: false
}
```

Essentially, just replacing the "`visible`" with "`false`"

- Restart/reboot, and it may work fine.