# Install Ubuntu on Toshiba Portege Z20T-C-12J alongside Windows

Tags: system-installation

Are there any problems installing Ubuntu on a **Toshiba Portege z20t-c-12j**?

I resized the windows partition, so there is a free space of 80GB, Then I used the Ubuntu 19.04 USB-live-distribution and everything seemed to work fine in the temporary system.

Is there anything special to take care of, that has to be done when installing Ubuntu on this device?

Comment: Can this z20t-c play 4k h265 video under linux? (For example a video coming out from a dji osmo action.)

Answer (score 0):

There were no problems during install. Just install Ubuntu on a USB device with **Unetbootin** or **Rufus** (Unetbootin can keep the existing data on your USB device and just add the install-image as extra folders).

But these are the optimizations I did after install:

### Optimization for installation of Ubuntu On toshiba portege z20t-c-12j

#### base install of missing applications

```
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
SYSTEMLANG=de
apt install unp audacious gimp gimp-help-de pidgin pidgin-otr haveged language-pack-$SYSTEMLANG language-pack-$SYSTEMLANG-base firefox-locale-de hunspell-$SYSTEMLANG-$SYSTEMLANG libreoffice-l10n-$SYSTEMLANG thunderbird-locale-$SYSTEMLANG inkscape fail2ban ncdu ccze dfc screen tmux sshfs keepass2 workrave dolphin chromium-browser krusader krename kompare kate p7zip audacity ttf-mscorefonts-installer ubuntu-restricted-extras etckeeper xfce4-goodies redshift meld htop atop fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console gnupg2 picard w3m curl wine make gcc g++ unzip gawk bzip2 yakuake onboard neovim tree psensor hardinfo kdiff3
```

#### Get rid of Lenses

```
apt remove unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks unity-scope-manpages unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-video-remote unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp unity-scope-zotero unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video
```

#### backgroundimages

https://askubuntu.com/a/1145869/34298

#### Keyboard-layout

[Configure Caps Lock as AltGr and Arrows like in vim](https://askubuntu.com/questions/684459/configure-caps-lock-as-altgr-and-arrows-like-in-vim)

#### fix nodejs

```
snap install --classic --edge node
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
snap install atom --classic
```

#### fix scrolling in Firefox

https://askubuntu.com/a/994483

### in case you use KDE or Kubuntu

[Plasmashell High CPU Load Fix - Plasma 5.15 KDE on Kubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162252/plasmashell-high-cpu-load-fix-plasma-5-15-kde-on-kubuntu-19-04)

#### fix default app okular:

https://www.ryananddebi.com/2014/09/29/linux-fixing-pdfs-opening-in-gimp-in-firefoxzotero/

Comment: Use `Rufus` instead of `unetbootin` as `unetbootin` isn't as reliable a tool as it used to be for creating live boot media. It fails a lot with UEFI systems. Works well enough for legacy BIOS though.

Comment: I have an ubuntu live-boot flash drive which I prepared with `rufus` that I also use to store files. If I don't touch the ubuntu files, the disk boots up fine and I get no errors. But when I boot live from the flash drive I wouldn't be able to access the files that I copied onto the flashdrive coz the whole device will have been mounted as `/` of the currently running live system and only the file system `filesystem.squashfs` is mounted as the whole partition. If you want to use your flash drive both for live boot and storage, you'd best create multiple partitions on it using `gparted`.

Comment: Ok, but can you flash a new image with Rufus on the stick without losing the existing data?

Comment: It doesn't matter what to use. If you already tested a LiveUSB and it works, you can use it to install the system.

Comment: @rubo77, `rufus` formats the drive before writing the new live disk so, no you'll definately lose ur existing data.